ZAP Proxy returning 404 for site in automated scan
I'm very new to ZAP so I'm sure there are obvious things I'm not understanding here.
I have a React app that I'm trying to scan in my corporate environment.
When I use the quick start and point at my site I get the error message:
Failed to attack the URL: received a 404 response code, expected 2xx
If I use the manual scan option I can see the site, I also get the HUD and can (to my knowledge) perform any of the tasks.
I have checked the ZAP.log file and can't see any issues.
I am running:

Linux Ubuntu 22.04.3 box
Java 21.0.2
ZAP 2.14.0
There is no proxy on my network
There is a self-signed certificate for the site I'm testing
I can SSLPoke the site with no issues
There is only one Java version installed
Site is considered secure by Firefox
I have installed a version of Firefox outside of snap install
I have set Selenium options to point to this version of Firefox
I have set the proxy of this browser to localhost:8080 including SSL sites
In Tools->Options->Network->Connection I have tried enabling unsafe SSL/TLS negotiation
The site being tested is running in a k8s cluster, the site can be viewed from Firefox with no issue
I've read the docs on connecting in corporate environments and FAQ on working with self-signed certificates to no avail.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

A 404 response means the page is not found: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404
The ZAP Quick Start scan will not run if the URL you specify is a 404 as its usually not that useful.
Try opening the URL in a browser - what does it show you?
You can still run the ZAP spiders against URL that returns a 404 and then run the active scanner...

Opening the site in the browser returns the site as expected with a 200 response.
I've turned on debug logging but it only shows failed to access URL. I can open the site using manual scanning and the results are returned back to ZAP, it's just the automated scan that doesn't find the site.

Strange. If you ask on the ZAP User Group we can look into it further https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users

https://groups.google.com/g/zaproxy-users/c/cCfAJeiGkpU I have posted this question here, thanks!

I believe I have found the culprit. No idea why (yet) but the VITE react site returns a 404 before actually loading the site. ZAP hits the 404 first and then doesn't continue on. I'm tipping that if the first response wasn't a 404 then the scan would have been fine.
